# turn value of row in column 1 into a variable and value of row in column 2 to be the value of variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I currently have a dataframe with 4 columns. I want to use the first column to create a variable and the second column to be the value of that variable. Col 1 is named Input and col 2 is named Value

```
df.loc[df['Input']=='variable1'['Value'].values
```

produces the value that the variable should be, but i have to specify variable1, variable2, etc.

id like to get a for loop that returns 'Input' as the new variable name and the code above as the value of that variable.

```
DF - 2 col

Input      | Value
Variable1  |  35
Variable2  |  187
.....
Variable17 |  19
```

the end result would be
Variable1 = 35
Variable2=  187

so i can then do things like

```
newdf['computation']=newdf['xyz']+Variable1-Variable2
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this. your Variable need to be set before doing this:

```
Variable1
# 34
df = pd.DataFrame() 
df= df.assign(Input='Variable' + pd.Series(range(1,10)).astype(str)) 
df['Value'] = df['Input'].apply(lambda x: eval(x))
```

output:

```
In [2202]: df                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[2202]: 
       Input  Value
0  Variable1     34
1  Variable2     37
2  Variable3     12
3  Variable4      9
4  Variable5     35
5  Variable6    127
6  Variable7     21
7  Variable8      2
8  Variable9     27
```

to go backwards:

df.set_index('Input')['Value'].to_dict()

```
{'Variable1': 34,
 'Variable2': 37,
 'Variable3': 12,
 'Variable4': 9,
 'Variable5': 35,
 'Variable6': 127,
 'Variable7': 21,
 'Variable8': 2,
 'Variable9': 27}
```

Comment: That approach works, but i dont want to list an ever changing amount of variables. I want this input file that feeds the dataframe to be the basis of my variables. Creating them in advance for 35 is not very efficient. Also the variables are not jsut numerical one after each other. it can be like p_e,sales,profit, etc

Comment: iMiller, you want to create the variables from the DF, so backward right? The best way to do that is to create a dict.

Comment: would i then just be able to call variable3 as an example or would i need to call it like a dictionary?

Comment: you'd need to call it like a dictionary. I'm not sure how to set it as a variable, or if that's even possible, as eval throws an error when i use equal in it